# Can not unmount an S3 directory mounted with s3fs-fuse

Tags: amazon-web-services, mount, amazon-s3, s3fs

I have an s3fs-fuse "device" mounted at `/mnt/s3`. I want to unmount it so that I can remount it with the `mp_umask` flag so that `chroot` will work properly.

The command **should** be:

```
fusermount -u /mnt/s3
```

Unfortunately the result is:

```
fusermount: failed to unmount /mnt/s3: Device or resource busy
```

That's not helpful. Shouldn't be this hard!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `lsof` to figure out which files are still open.

Answer (score 13):

The command that worked was:

```
umount -l /mnt/s3
```

Comment: This might not unmount the filesystem if one of the opens is long-lived; it is better to actually close the open files.

Comment: In my case there were no open files, unmounting using that command did work for me.